# Alternative to Survey Monkey's Audience & Advanced Branching Logic

Tags: survey

I wish to use Survey Monkey's [Advanced Branching Logic](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Advanced-Branching-Rules) along with their [Survey Monkey Audience](https://www.surveymonkey.com/mp/audience/).

Unfortunately I need to pay for a year of Advanced Branching Logic by signing up for a [Platinum plan](https://www.surveymonkey.com/pricing/), rather than being able to pay for the Platinum plan monthly.

I've asked Survey Monkey and they will not offer the Platinum plan on a monthly contract.

**What I need:**

I need a survey tool that:

1. Offers conditional logic, i.e, being able to show or hide questions based on answers to previous questions
2. Offers paid survey completions, i.e, I pay $X per survey completion, and I can choose what type of audience to take the survey, e.g, small business owners.

**Contender:**

[Google Consumer Surveys](https://www.google.com/insights/consumersurveys/home) allows you to choose your audience, but does not offer conditional logic.

Help appreciated.

Regards,
Steve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SmartSurvey.co.uk](http://SmartSurvey.co.uk) offers `skip logic` on their [pro plan](https://www.smartsurvey.co.uk/pricing).

This lets me set up the equivalent of [Gravity Forms](http://www.GravityForms.com) conditional loading of questions.

[Smart Survey also allow you to buy responses through their consumer panels](https://www.smartsurvey.co.uk/consumer-panels).